# wordpress custom permalinks not working with sub category on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

i have created custom permalink in wordpress with custom structure

> "localhost/myWebSite /%category%/%postname%/".

i have multiple categories.

when the permalink is `'localhost/myWebSite/category/post-name'` it works perfectly.

but when permalink is `'localhost/myWebSite/parent-category/sub-category/post-name'` it shows page not found.

my htaccess file is:-

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /umimpex/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /umimpex/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

i have tried to change access permission of httpd file to rewrite but nothing works.

Comment: Once, update  permalink from setting (first select -> plain and save, again select post name and save )

Comment: @AnilKum tried that for 10 times. but it didn't wordked.

Comment: Are both of parent category and subcategory selected for the post? If you select only one of them, the permalink doesn't include parents or children.

Comment: @karuna can you load the page for `localhost/myWebSite/parent-category/sub-category/` with HTTP 200? It should list the posts with the specified categories. Please also try other variations of categories in URL and check the category base in the permalinks page of settings.

Comment: I got this problem before. I'm using Apache on WAMP. I just enable the **rewrite_module** and the problem have been solved. Try it. @karuna

Comment: I've seen so much messing around with custom post types + categories in permalink here, I'd just use this plugin

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

It has worked every time, unless demands were super exceptional.

Comment: @crew i have already removed the '#' from  `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and  Changed all occurrences of `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` and restarted the xampp, but still getting the 404 error.